# Alterar valores na página html usando javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho este formulário que é de uma bilheteira em html, mas quero que funcione usando javascript, ao cliclar no botao de + ou - para alterar a quantidade e alterar o valor total.

Estive a pesquisar e vi a tag *output* estive a testar mas não consegui efetuar uma boa implementação com os botões...

[image: formulario bilheteira]

o código html que tenho é o seguinte

```
<tr class="linha-meio borda-topo">
        <td class="divisao-direita">CRIANÇA (3 - 12 ANOS)</td>
        <td>13,78 €</td>
        <td class="alinhar-direita">
            <button class="botao-quantidade">&#10134;</button>
            <a class="quantidade">0</a>
            <button class="botao-quantidade">&#10133;</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="linha-meio">
        <td class="divisao-direita">ADULTO (13 - 64 ANOS)</td>
        <td>21,38 €</td>
        <td class="alinhar-direita">
            <button class="botao-quantidade">&#10134;</button>
            <a class="quantidade">2</a>
            <button class="botao-quantidade">&#10133;</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="borda-fundo">
        <td class="divisao-direita">SÉNIOR (+65 ANOS)</td>
        <td>15,20 €</td>
        <td class="alinhar-direita">
            <button class="botao-quantidade">&#10134;</button>
            <a class="quantidade">0</a>
            <button class="botao-quantidade">&#10133;</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="nao-mudar-cor-1">
        <td></td>
        <th class="alinhar-direita">Total:</th>
        <td class="alinhar-direita">42.76€ c/iva</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Se puderem ajudar agradecia, sou novato com javaScript

Comment: *"vi a tag output"* tag output? não conheço isso e não vi sua pergunta, consegue colocar um exemplo? fiquei curioso. Sobre sua dúvida, já criou algum codigo `javascript`?  crie uma function associada ao evento "click" dos botões, e de acordo com o botão (+/-) vc soma ou subtrai o valor e altera no elemento "quantidade". Aliás, onde aparece a quantidade precisa ser um link? não poderia ser um span ou div?

Comment: @RicardoPontual eu vi neste link [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_output.asp) dá para fazer umas coisas, mas acho que não é o ideal para aqui... Já consegui colocar a quantidade a funcionar com a resposta abaixo, só está a faltar calcular o total em função da quantidade selecionada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá eu farei um exemplo aqui de como poderia ser a solução, mas existem várias maneiras de resolver o problema.

Em meu exemplo eu adicionei id nos seguintes elementos, você possivelmente deverá utilizar id em todos os elementos.

```
 <a id="qtdcrianca" class="quantidade">0</a>
 <button id="addqtdcrianca" class="botao-quantidade">&#10133;</button>
 <td id="agregadototal" class="alinhar-direita">42.76€ c/iva</td>
```

Aqui está a parte dos scripts.

```
<script>
   function adicionarValorCrianca() {
     let el = document.getElementById("qtdcrianca")
     let valor = parseInt(el.text)
     valor += 1
     el.text = valor
     atualizarTotal()
   }
   function atualizarTotal() {
     let total = 0
     let el = document.getElementById("qtdcrianca")
     let valor = parseInt(el.text)
     const totalcrianca = 13.78
     total = valor * totalcrianca
     const adulto = 21.38
     let el1 = document.getElementById("qtdadulto")
     let valor1 = parseInt(el1.text)
     total += valor1 * adulto
     console.log(total)
    const totalcstr = document.getElementById("agregadototal").textContent = total.toFixed(2)+'€ c/iva'
   }
   elemento = document.getElementById("addqtdcrianca")
   elemento.addEventListener("click", adicionarValorCrianca); 
</script>
```

Para poder atualizar o valor, no final do método que faz o incremento você deve chamar a rotina que atualiza o valor total. Atualizei o html e o script.

Essa seria uma implementação simples dos seus requisitos, dá pra melhorar bem mais, este exemplo inclusive criar um método compartilhado para adicionar ou decrementar valores.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Muito bom !! os botões estão a funcionar, consegui perceber o código e já o repliquei para as outras colunas. Mas agora falta a parte em que calcula o valor total.... podias-me dar uma ajuda?

Comment: Atualizei com uma ideia de implementação, não sei se você pode utilizar variáveis declaradas dentro do js. se não puder, terá que fazer um passo a mais de pegar os elementos e fazer o parse pra integer, antes de fazer a soma.

Comment: já implementei o código, só que claro está a faltar atualizar o valor total, como é que vou fazer isso? sempre que houver uma alteração na página ou com uma função que verifica a cada segundo? e para atualizar o valor é a função `atualizarTotal` que tenho que chamar?

Comment: Se você verificar eu atualizei a resposta. Na function  `adicionarValorCrianca()`eu adicionei uma nova linha, que é a chamada para atualizar o valor total. O valor total deve ser atualizado sempre que houver um clique de botão.

Comment: ahh sim, eu vi mas depois esqueci de passar essa parte. Está a funcionar tudo muito bem, obrigado. Agora ainda há uma melhoria possivel, era de não deixar os números ficarem negativos, mas assim já está bom, obrigado pela ajuda